# How do you kill a Windows Service with Cygwin?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cygwin, services

I've found many [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/439539/how-to-kill-a-windows-process-in-a-cygwin-terminal)/[answers](https://superuser.com/a/1760724/89165) that document how to kill a Windows *process* in Cygwin, but *I'm asking how to kill a Windows 10 **service** in Cygwin*.

If the verb "kill" seems out of place for a Windows service, I'm referring to the effect you get by highlighting it in the Task Manager and pressing the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

[image]

(I don't know if this is of any significance, but as you can see from the screenshot, this particular service is under the "Background processes" section of the task manager, it's within "Program Files", and it is a standalone `.exe`. Most of the other services I see are in the "Windows processes" section, within "System32", and run via arguments to the `svchost.exe` command, respectively.)

I can find the service's process ID by running this command in cygwin: `wmic service get ProcessID, Name, State /format:csv | tr -d '\r' | grep -i -- 'service name'`:

```
DESKTOP,ServiceNameLoggerService,0,Stopped
DESKTOP,ServiceNameSvc,19724,Running
```

But I get an unhelpful message if I attempt to kill it:

```
$ /bin/kill -f -W 19724
kill: couldn't open pid 19724
```

I *am* able to kill normal Windows processes that command, but not this one.

In your answer, it's okay if a Windows command kills the service, so long as that command runs within a Cygwin terminal and doesn't require me to *start* the terminal with admin access<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup>: The reason I don't want to start Cygwin with admin access is because I'm running my Cygwin terminal in VS Code. According to my research, [the integrated terminal has the same permissions as VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_how-do-i-create-an-admin-terminal), which I'm starting as a regular user. I could start VS Code as an admin, but this has undesirable side effects. For example, [you can't upgrade VS Code in admin mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_user-setup-versus-system-setup).

[Elsewhere, official sources say](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-profiles):

> The integrated terminal shell is running with the permissions of VS Code. If you need to run a shell command with elevated (administrator) or different permissions, use platform utilities such as `runas.exe` within a terminal.

I spent an hour trying to figure out how to get `runas.exe` to work in Cygwin with no luck. No consistent luck, anyway. It seemed to randomly tell me my username/password was invalid the majority of the time.

Besides, I create and kill Cygwin terminals frequently, and the pop-up asking me to confirm if I want to run in Admin mode would have a negative effect on my productivity. (Maybe there's a way to disable this per app, in which case, this would be a moot point.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this works in Cygwin, but the standard syntax for [net](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html). from the command prompt or in a batch file, is `net stop <serviceName>`. E.G., to stop *Delivery Optimization* service, with filename *DoSvc*, either of the following would work:

```
net stop "delivery optimization"

net stop dosvc
```

Notes:

- The command must be run as Administrator.
- It is not case sensitive.
- Other *net* commands can *start*, *pause* or *continue* the service.
- Use quotes around a service name with a space.

[image: net stop service]

BTW, *killing* a Windows Service process is often ineffective, because many services are set to restart on failure.

Comment: It's fine by me if the *task* has administrator privileges so long as cygwin terminal doesn't need to start with them.

Comment: @DanielKaplan - You can’t start a task with Administrative permissions unless the terminal that starts it also has it, obviously, any process started with a user with Administrative permissions will be started with the lowest permissions possible unless explicitly elevated.

Comment: @Ramhound I see. That wasn't obvious to me because in the Windows GUI I perform actions that require Administrative access to perform. I thought there would be an analogous form of that within the terminal. Can you explain what the quote at the bottom of my question is saying, because it seems to be at odds with your comment?

Comment: Using “runas” to run a process as a user who is an Administrator will NOT elevate the permissions of the process to that of an Administrator. You can elevate a processes permission started in a terminal window that itself had it’s permissions elevated.